# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages when to install libvulkan-dev

Tags: package-management

```
sudo apt-get install libvulkan-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvulkan-dev : Depends: libvulkan1 (= 1.1.97-2) but 1.2.162.0-1~bpo10+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can install it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you already did something similar in the past but aren't handling it the same way: using *buster-backports*.

If you're adding packages from *buster-backports*, you must continue to use those backports packages, because downgrade is not allowed by default. Your installed version of `libvulkan1` is from *buster-backports* already so is automatically the candidate because it's a newer version than from simply *buster*. As `libvulkan-dev`'s version is in lock-step with `libvulkan1`'s version (they are from the same source) you have no other choice than use *buster-backports* for `libvulkan-dev` too. So in the end:

```
apt-get -t buster-backports install libvulkan-dev
```